# Ruby on Rails - 404 response - "The page you were looking for doesn't exit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I've been stuck on this error of "The page you were looking for doesn't exit" for a while now. Does anyone know how to solve it?

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'heroku', '3.0.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :production do
      gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
      gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Heroku is installed in the bundle list.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 698 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs     vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
```

Any ideas? I'm really stuck.

I have been following the railstutorial.org

Comment: What are you trying to load that you're getting the 404?  the homepage of your app? 0.o

Comment: $ heroku open, I'm still in the setup phase

Comment: make ur question clear, otherwise no one will be able to help u in real. what u r trying and what is not working?

Comment: I've yet to deploy on heroku myself, but it appears when you do `heroku open` it only opens your web browser to the application.  So your 404 is really when it tries to load a homepage, do you have a homepage setup?  you have something in your routes.rb file saying where the root is?

Comment: You need to grab the logs off Heroku.  Type "heroku logs" in the console and paste them here.

Comment: Whenever I get this error on Heroku it was usually because the database was not migrated.